# We don't want client programmers be able to access methods from a class We inherit

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance

Good morning,

we are making a wrapper that will be used by our clients. They are also programmers.

To make this more clear, I'm gonna use an example of What we wanna achieve:

A --> B --> C

We've created solution B that inherits from solution A. Project A is an external library that We are using and we cannot be modified.

Clients are programming in project C and they are using our wrapper (Project B) to make controls. As project B inherits from Project A, they can use A methods.

They asked Us if We could block the access to project A methods as some of them could use those and make bad use of it...

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use inheritance, then base class methods will necessarily be available.  Can you do composition/forwarding instead?  If your type contains an object from library A and forwards to it, then clients will only be able to use the methods that you expose.  This will necessarily involve boilerplate code, though there are alternatives that might allow reducing it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If they have access to the DLL then you're in hot water. They can decomile it using https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/#section=web-installer (free). There is little to stop them accessing the DLL directly, cutting your wrapper out.

I would recommend adding some code-based security to library A so that methods can only be called if a valid licence key is passed in. That way, project B can call the methods by providing a valid key, but project C would not be able to do so. There is a probably a clever way of setting a license globally, but I can quite think how to stop C calling A if B is sat in the middle and has globally set the license.

Another way would be to override the Methods and mark them as private in project B - so you can call them in project B, but they wouldn't be visible in project C. However, that doesn't stop them consuming the assembly dll directly if they have access to it.